# R and jupyter notebook installation problems

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook

- am following instructions from
  https://irkernel.github.io/installation/ so i can use R with jupyter
  notebook.
- i already have jupyter and R installed, and they work fine.
- so when it comes to installing the packages with:

`install.packages(c('repr', 'IRdisplay', 'evaluate', 'crayon', 'pbdZMQ', 'devtools', 'uuid', 'digest'))`

i get this message:

> In R CMD INSTALL
>   * installing *source* package 'repr' ...
>   ** package 'repr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   Error in .read_description(dfile) :
>     file 'C:/Users/????/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCI01gk/R.INSTALL6e03e7f2fb2/repr/DESCRIPTION' does not exist
>   ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'repr'
>   * removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library/repr'
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>           'C:\Users\????\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpY9TPCg\downloaded_packages'
>   Warning message:
>   In install.packages("repr") :
>     installation of package 'repr' had non-zero exit status
>   install.packages('devtools')
>   trying URL 'https://cran.usthb.dz/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/devtools_2.0.1.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 384476 bytes (375 KB)
>   downloaded 375 KB

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running the install.packages command? If you are running that in Jupyter Notebook it will fail. Make sure that you don't do this in your RStudio console, but in a regular R terminal. See the blog post [Jupyter And R Markdown: Notebooks With R](https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/jupyter-notebook-r) from DataCamp.